# (Rails) In-place editing of attributes via an "index" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, spreadsheet, in-place-edit

I'm looking to use "in_place_editor_field" on an "Index" page of items.  Basically I want to mimic spreadsheet functionality for pre-existing line items in order to edit their attributes.  However, none of the "in_place_editor" examples I've seen provide any useful real-world application of this nature.

Also, a lot of the existing code examples don't work.  I'm aware that the code was removed from Core, but even after installing it as a plugin, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas?

Best.

Comment: any errors? if yes please post

Comment: My experience is *very* similar to this:  (http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=514).  I need to allow for editing with a list of items, not just a single item.  Not simultaneous editing, but all viewable at once (e.g. a spreadsheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing. I found an example at http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.0/tutorial/railstut.html
Scroll all the way to the bottom and look at index.html.erb.

The trick is that in_place_editor_field needs to work on an instance variable, so inside your loop, you need to set an instance variable and pass that to the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this example is better:

```
<table>
    <tr>   
        <th>First name</th>   
        <th>Last name</th> 
    </tr>  
    <% @person.each do |person| %>
        <tr>  
            <td><%= best_in_place person, :first_name %></td>  
            <td><%= best_in_place person, :last_name %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

I got this from [this page](http://linksxplored.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/in-place-editing-in-rails.html)